# Android, want to reference Bitmaps in array using strings, programatically

Tags: android, arrays, image, uniqueidentifier

I'm looking for a nice programatic way I can use to refer to the images in my Bitmap[].

At the moment, I declare a bunch of integers in my class

```
Bitmap[] mBmp = new Bitmap[6]    
int image1 = 0, image2 = 1, image3 = 2, someimage = 3, otherimage = 4, yetanoimage = 5;
```

I then refer to them as follows:

```
mBmp[someimage] ...
```

However, this is inefficient and I would like to refer to them (preferrably) according to their filename (minus the extension) or some other unique identifier than can be programatically determined.

The reason for this is that:

1. number of images is arbitrary
2. file names are arbitrary
3. I want to automate the process as a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have to use an array? Why don't you use an [Hashtable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) to store your bitmaps? That way you could fetch them using their (unique) filename as their identifier.

As per the example, inserting bitmaps:

```
Hashtable<String, Bitmap> bitmaps = new Hashtable<String, Bitmap>();
numbers.put("one_image", bitmap1);
numbers.put("image_two", bitmap2);
numbers.put("beach_house", bitmap3);
```

And fetching bitmaps:

```
bitmap = bitmaps.get("beach_house");
```

Comment: Actually, the reason I use the array is because i refer to my images in a combination of filename (for unique files, or the first in a series) and index (for images in a series following the uniquely named first one). Has Map works, but I have implemented it differently, by putting the index of the bitmap in it's array into the hashmap rather than the bitmap itself.

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would be to put your images into a HashMap.  A Map is like an Array but with an object that works as the key.  In this case, I'm suggesting you use a String object as the key.  Map is the collection type, and HashMap is an implementation of Map.

To create a hashmap you'd do something like:

```
Map<String, Bitmap> myPictures = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
```

To Insert an image:

```
String fileName = "somefileName";
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decode(fileName)
myPictures.put(fileName, bitmap)
```

Retrieving a bitmap can then be done like so:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = myPictures.get(filename)
```

You can iterate over the bitmaps by doing:

```
for(Bitmap bitmap : myPictures.values()){
   display(bitmap);
}
```